# Robot Framework: Accessing web application and associated web objects with Edge Chromium IE Mode

Tags: python, internet-explorer, robotframework, selenium-edgedriver, microsoft-edge-chromium

While I can perform test automation of web applications in Edge Chromium using Selenium 4 and latest RobotFramework-SeleniumLibrary, legacy IE sites require Edge to be in IE mode.

I’m not sure how to enable this in Python Robot Framework?

I really don’t know! I might want to do something like:

> Open Browser | ${url} | Edge | options=use_chromium=True, desired_capability=ie

Anyone have a better idea or want to take a guess how to achieve this?